# Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 unattended install fails with "No matching physical volumes found"

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, desktop-environments, preseed, ubiquity

I have an ISO image that is booting from a partition on my SSD that was created by UNetbootin and it automatically starts the install.  This is the same SSD that I am trying to install on which I know is strange. It does run my `ubiquity/early_command` & `partman/early_command` as expected so I know that it is picking up the preseed file correctly.

If I `Ctrl-Alt-f2` to get to a console window all I get is a blank text screen with the cursor in the upper left hand corner.

In the install window I get the error "Ubuntu partman: No matching physical  volumes found."
[Verifying the installation configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJdkl.jpg)

I understand that no one would normally use the same drive for the install media and the target, but this is not a normal situation.  We have several thousand of these units in the field with Windows 7 already installed and running.  We are trying to create a process that can replace the existing Windows installation with Linux and do this in a way that requires no user interaction or intervention, and we *really* don't want to have them returned to the factory for re-imaging. I am already able to create the new partition for the ISO, copy the ISO files into the new partition, then reboot into the Linux installer, and remove the existing NTFS partitions using the `partman/early_command` with a simple bash script.

If I cannot get partman to create the partitions I need, would it be possible to create them myself in my bash script using `fdisk` or `parted`?

My grub command line is: `kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/my.seed boot=casper auto=true priority=critical BOOT_DEBUG=3 log_host=172.25.7.148 log_port=514 automatic-ubiquity noprompt quiet splash ---`

here is my seed file:

```
### Localization --- Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
ubiquity    languagechooser/language-name   select English
ubiquity    countrychooser/shortlist    select US 
ubiquity    time/zone   select  America/Chicago 
ubiquity    debian-installer/locale select en_US.UTF-8 
ubiquity    localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_US.UTF-8 
ubiquity    console-setup/ask_detect    boolean false 
ubiquity    console-setup/layoutcode    string us
ubiquity    console-setup/modelcode string SKIP
ubiquity    keyboard-configuration/variant  select English (US)
ubiquity    keyboard-configuration/layout   select English (US)
ubiquity    keyboard-configuration/model    select Generic 105-key (Intl) PC
ubiquity    console-keymaps-at/keymap   select us
ubiquity    keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap   select us
ubiquity    ubiquity/reboot boolean true
ubiquity    ubiquity/early_command string /cdrom/presee/early-install.sh

console-setup   console-setup/layoutcode    string us
console-setup   console-setup/layout    select U.S. English
console-setup   console-setup/variantcode   select U.S. English

ubiquity    ubiquity/success_command string [ -x /cdrom/preseed/finish-install.sh ] && /cdrom/preseed/finish-install.sh
ubiquity    ubiquity/failure_command string [ -x /cdrom/preseed/failed-install.sh ] && /cdrom/preseed/failed-install.sh

# Install the Ubuntu desktop.
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect ubuntu-desktop


# Verbose output and no boot splash screen
d-i debian-installer/quiet  boolean false
d-i debian-installer/splash boolean false

### Network configuration #########################################################################

# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# If you have a slow dhcp server and the installer times out waiting for it, this might be useful.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60
d-i netcfg/dhcpv6_timeout string 60

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string pc-name
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
# The wacky dhcp hostname that some ISPs use as a password of sorts.
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_hostname string radish

# If non-free firmware is needed for the network or other hardware, you can
# configure the installer to always try to load it, without prompting. Or
# change to false to disable asking.
#d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true

### User sccounts #################################################################################
# Root password, either in clear text
d-i passwd/root-password password Chang3M3
d-i passwd/root-password-again password Chang3M3

# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Maestro Player
d-i passwd/username string someusername
# Normal user's password, either in clear text
d-i passwd/user-password password Chang3M3
d-i passwd/user-password-again password Chang3M3

### Clocks / Time Zone ############################################################################
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string US/Central

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning ##################################################################################
# remove existing NTFS partitions.
d-i partman/early_command string /bin/bash /cdrom/preseed/removeNtfs.sh

ubiquity    partman-auto/method string regular
#ubiquity    partman/alignment select optimal
#ubiquity    partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
ubiquity    partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
ubiquity    partman-lvm/confirm string boolean true
ubiquity    partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /usr, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

ubiquity    partman/confirm_write_new_label string boolean true
ubiquity    partman/choose_partition select finish
ubiquity    partman/confirm string boolean true
ubiquity    partman/confirm_nooverwrite string boolean true

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Set to true if you want to encrypt the first user's home directory.
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string boot-root :: \
 45000 90000 500000 ext4 method{ format } format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } mountpoint{ / } . \
 50% 4096 80% linux-swap method{ swap } format{ } .

#d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root
ubiquity partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root

### Package selection ##################################################################################
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none

# By default, the system's locate database will be updated after the
# installer has finished installing most packages. This may take a while, so
# if you don't want it, you can set this to "false" to turn it off.
#d-i pkgsel/updatedb boolean true

d-i apt-setup/multiarch string i386

# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

**Update:** I can now get to the syslog while the installer is running.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant section of the log.  The message "No NTFS partions found dude!" is from my partman/early_command script that looks for and removes any existing NTFS partitions, so I know that it is at least running.

I have also updated my preseed file above to match what I am currently working with.

`Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu ubiquity[5125]: Step_before = stepLanguage
Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu activate-dmraid: No Serial ATA RAID disks detected
Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu preseed: running preseed command partman/early_command: /bin/bash /cdrom/preseed/removeNtfs.sh
Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu log-output: 
Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu log-output: No NTFS partions found dude!
Feb 20 17:13:02 ubuntu kernel: [   28.461231] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  5740 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.529244] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  4088 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.597244] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  5065 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.665237] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  5221 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.733234] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  9185 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.801233] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  6523 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.869233] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 12580 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   28.937239] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 14467 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.005235] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 16643 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.005237] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 16643 MB/s
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.005239] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.011845] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.049238]    avx       : 19933.000 MB/sec
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.080268] Btrfs loaded
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.119195] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu kernel: [   29.161439] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu partman:   No matching physical volumes found
Feb 20 17:13:03 ubuntu partman:   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Feb 20 17:13:19 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[4884]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Feb 20 17:13:20 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[4457]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Feb 20 17:13:52 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[4884]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Feb 20 17:16:31 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[4884]: message repeated 3 times: [ wlp2s0: Failed to initiate sched scan]
Feb 20 17:17:01 ubuntu CRON[7163]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are removing a partition which is still required during setup. Maybe if you do use the netboot installer for your setup it will work better.

I am using an approach where I embed all required files into the [initrd.gz](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/blob/master/ubuntu/17.04/build-iso.sh#L43) file of the netboot installer. Therefore I do not require the mounted ISO during setup. Not sure if this might fix your problem.

Anyway, [here](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/blob/master/ubuntu/16.04/custom/preseed.cfg) is the self-contained preseed configuration. It is part of a [project](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/) which provides all you need to create an unattended installation of a minimal setup of Linux, whereas minimal translates to the most lightweight setup - including an OpenSSH service and Python - which you can derive from the standard installer of a Ubuntu distribution.